# Running a Qt app over the web

Tags: c++, linux, qt, web-applications

I am writing an application using Qt and want to try and deploy it as a web-application. I want user's to be able to use my application by accessing it through a web browser. I'm guessing that's what a web-application is? What kind of options do I have? I've never looked into doing anything like this but I'd like to learn something new.

EDIT: What if I deployed my application on a Linux server and had users access/run it through a terminal? I think writing web application is going to be more complicated than I had originally thought.

Comment: Web applications and desktop applications typically use very different concepts. You can't take a Qt application and make it run in the browser. There is Google NaCl, but that's limited and probably not what you want anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you have is a Qt application, then the best you can do is use Qt 5 and run it using a remote visualization package:

1. [Use WebGL streaming](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/07/07/qt-webgl-streaming-merged/), introduced in Qt 5.10. Qt exposes a browser-connectible interface directly, without need for third-party code.
2. For Qt 5.0-5.9, you can use the vnc platform plugin. Then connect using [a web-browser based vnc client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240633/web-based-vnc-client).

For many uses it might be sufficient, and certainly it's much less effort than coding up a web app.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for Wt which provides a different set of drawing routines for many Qt GUI elements, turning them from lines on screen to HTML controls.

http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt

It also handles websocket calls to provide interactivity. It seems a great idea, let us know how it works in practice.

Comment: 6 years later, is Wt still a viable option?  I'd prefer to stick to C++ and Python and skip JS as it says on the linked website.

Comment: @mLstudent33 then you'll probably want wxWidgets which is still around, but I dount Wt was anything more than an interesting idea of using web tech for a UI. Today, you might as well write a web UI in javascript or wasm and write the good stuff behind an API. JS sucks but for a UI, it works and there are lots of good libraries like d3, so don't sweat it too much.

Answer (score 4):

For the case of QML there is [QmlWeb](https://gitorious.org/qmlweb/pages/Home) which is a JavaScript library that is able to parse QML-code and create a website out of it using normal HTML/DOM elements and absolute positions within CSS, translating the QML properties into CSS properties.

QmlWeb is a small project by Lauri Paimen that he’s already developing for a few years now. QmlWeb of course doesn’t yet support everything Qt’s implementation of QML does, but it already supports a quite usable subset of it. It supports nearly all of the most basic QML syntax. Moreover it has support for HTML input elements (Button, TextInput, TextArea are currently supported, more to come).

Well, QmlWeb is not finished. I hope Digia help with this project to make it ready with mature features.

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, it is possible to compile Qt applications to javascript using emscripten-qt. These run fairly fast with Firefox's asm.js interpreter:

http://vps2.etotheipiplusone.com:30176/redmine/projects/emscripten-qt/wiki

Answer (score 3):

Try ["Qt for Webassembly"](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/05/22/qt-for-webassembly-examples/).

[Webassembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly) allows the C/C++ code to be compiled and run natively inside majority of the browsers:

> WebAssembly (Wasm, WA) is a web standard that defines a binary format and a corresponding assembly-like text format for executable code in Web pages. ... It is executed in a sandbox in the web browser after a verification step. Programs can be compiled from high-level languages into Wasm modules and loaded as libraries from within JavaScript applets ... Its initial aim is to support compilation from C and C++, though support for other source languages such as Rust and .NET languages is also emerging.

Answer (score 1):

To run a Qt application unchanged over the web so users can operate it in a browser, you can compile it for Android using the `x86` [Android ABI](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis), run it inside an Android emulator on a server and **supply the Android Cast videostream** to users' browsers. You'll also need to have JavaScript in place that records the keyboard and mouse events on the web clients and relays them back to the server.

I had previously [tried Qt WebGL streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63488830) and found it to be good over the local network but too slow over the Internet. A 10 s application startup time is acceptable, but 3 s to show a new screen is rather not. I had the exact same experience with the Qt VNC platform plugin. Compared with that, the Android Cast streaming based appetize.io solution (see below) was much faster, providing a well usable user experience even over my 8 Mbit/s connection.

### Existing solutions

Here is an overview of commercial products and open source software components that I found that can help you with this approach:

- **[appetize.io](https://appetize.io/).** This is a commercial product to run Android applications over the web for demo and testing purposes. I have just done this with a Qt QML based application and liked the outcome. When choosing an Android 9 / 10 device you can see that the "Screencast" setting is on; which is why I believe that this solution uses the Android Cast technology.
- **[runthatapp.com](https://runthatapp.com/).** This is another commercial offer. Not as sophisticated (yet) as appetize.io, but providing a nice pay-as-you-go scheme.
- **[ScreenStream](https://github.com/dkrivoruchko/ScreenStream).** An open source Android app that provides a web server to view the screen of one Android device in a web browser, also relying on the Android Cast technology. That Android device could be an emulator running on a web server. And to make this multi-user capable you can employ a small load balancer similar to [a technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63488830) that I developed for Qt WebGL streaming. The ScreenStream README shows that the application might consume up to 20 Mbit/s per client in short bursts.

### Ideas for future improvements

Serving your Qt app as an interactive live video stream seems a promising idea to me, given that I found it already less sluggish than VNC and similar solutions. There are ways to make this even faster, such as using a hardware H.265 video encoder to create a video stream with very little delay. By operating multiple such encoders on a single server, the server could serve multiple clients and still keep its CPU load low. Maybe there are even better video formats for such a purpose, given that user interfaces of programs lend themselves well to lossless compression.

### Some hints for appetize.io

Finally: since I used the appetize.io product for a Qt application over the last few days, here are some tips from that experience:

- It is necessary to compile your Qt application for the `x86` Android ABI. The default `armeabi-v7a` ABI will not work because most appetize.io devices are actually server-based Android emulators and the only ARM based device ("Nexus 5 Physical") failed to start any Qt application I tried to use with it.

  The `x86_64` ABI may also work, but you might then have to also compile Qt yourself for it, as not all versions of Qt come pre-compiled for that architecture.
- All appetize.io links (both for standalone pages and embeddable iframes) support [GET parameters to configure the app presentation format](https://appetize.io/docs#). Especially relevant here is `screenOnly=true` to show the app without a picture of a phone or tablet around it.
- Features that rely on phone hardware (camera, position etc.) will not work or only show dummy data. But if you really wanted, you could create a hybrid application combined with client-side JavaScript. It would run device-dependent code in the user's browser, for example to take a photo with the webcam, and then provide the results to the Qt application via the [appetize.io cross-document messaging protocol](https://appetize.io/docs#cross-document-messages). The following message types seem suitable to build a simple communication protocol: `pasteText(value)`, `keypress(key, shiftKey)` and `openUrl(value)`.
- In the default appetize.io standalone app demo pages, only the key events of ordinary letter keys are sent to the app, not keyboard shortcuts or function keys like <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>. This might be possible to fix with JavaScript on an own page embedding the appetize.io iframe, as their [cross-document messaging protocol](https://appetize.io/docs#cross-document-messages) provides the `keypress(key, shiftKey)` message type.

Answer (score 0):

Qt does not support writing browser based web applications. Unfortunately.

You need to use common web programming technologies for this. There are a lot of ways, but Qt is not one of them.

Comment: Qt5 has a wasm build, can run on browser