# Qt widgets within web page

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I wonder if there is a way to port an application written in Python and PyQt into a web browser. So instead of running the application from a local drive it would run straight from a web and being displayed within a web browser such as Chrome or Firefox. Just like a "normal" application it would allow the user to input or select values using QLineEdits, QComboBoxes, QListWidgets and etc but all within a web browser. Since the application's GUI is written in PyQt I wonder if the same Qt widgets used in its "standalone" version somehow could be "ported" to a web browser. If moving all the Qt widgets to a web browser not an option please suggest where to start. What Python modules are needed, what learning resources and etc.

Comment: You can see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517954/running-a-qt-app-over-the-web/24522984

Comment: Also, you can take a look at [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt). It will require you to write another front-end/user interface with Wt widgets, but you can utilize Qt and other C++ libraries with it. I don't know if Wt has bindings for Python.