# How to implement labelImg function on the web browser

Tags: deep-learning, annotations, labelimg

i am using labelImg tool for a graphical image annotation.
But for our education site, we would like to add this function of a graphical image annotation like labelImg into our web service.
https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg

So Can we make labelling tool for data preparation for training on our website as one of function of data training?

Anyone have any idea concerned with this?

Ryan.

Comment: Have you managed to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Labelimg is a desktop app that uses Qt for its UI. There exists solutions to run Qt in a Browser. See for example the solutions for [Running Qt over the Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517954/running-a-qt-app-over-the-web).

Otherwise I would recommend to explore other web-based tools for image annotation, e.g., the [Computer Vision Annotation Tool (CVAT)](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/cvat).

I hope you succeed in your endeavor.

To previous flags/deletion of my answer: As per Stackoverflow's code of conduct I did "make sure my answer provides at least a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful". Please comment with further explanation why this is not a valid answer. Many thanks and all the best.